# Privilege (Access/Permission) Control for Hierarchial Structured Resource

Tags: security, access-control, document-management

Question: Is there any standard model or industry defacto implementation for modeling and implementing Access Control in (i.e.) a Document Management System?

Note: I studied a bit the security mechanism of Windows (which I do not want to use), and I saw Users and Groups and Policies.

But I can't understand:

1 - How a single policy object can contain all information about allowed/denied actions on a subject for all users and groups, at a specific moment of time.

2 - How multiple policies on a specific subject, merge into one to provide least possible access.

3 - What is the mechanism (data structures, database, caching, implementation) of hierarchical resources like folders? Those king of queries are usually slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is.

There are two parts to this:

- First of all there is an authorization model called attribute-based access control or ABAC. ABAC extends the capabilities of the more well-known role-based access control model or RBAC. RBAC is user-centric and doesn't cater for the use cases you have. ABAC can help you write policies that take into account user, resource, action, and context attributes e.g. *a manager can edit the document he/she owns* or *a manager can view all the documents that are draft and belong to the same department.*
- Secondly, there is a standard called XACML (eXtensible Access Control Markup Language) which implements ABAC in a technology-neutral way. XACML defines:

  - an architecture with the notion of a policy enforcement point and policy decision point.
  - a request/response scheme
  - an attribute-based policy language

You can read more on both topics at:

- NIST's [ABAC reference site](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/)
- [OASIS XACML website](http://oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml)

Comment: Thanks, I've looked the standard documentation and generated some source code based on xsd; and yet It seems complicated and I have not found so many projects (especially open source ones) use this standard; or rather an expected level of activity in these standards. Am I missing something?

Comment: BTW I am developing in .NET land (C# to be specific).

Comment: The company I work for - Axiomatics - provides a .NET PDP engine that you can embed w/in your .NET App. If you want free/open source, your best bet is Balana. It's in Java but it exposes a web service interface you can use.